# how to get all the custom audience data withOUT limit using the facebook graph edge?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

let's say I have this custom audience query

```
v2.8/act_122343252366/?fields=customaudiences{account_id,approximate_count,data_source,delivery_status,description,id,is_value_based,lookalike_audience_ids,lookalike_spec,name,operation_status,opt_out_link,permission_for_actions,pixel_id,retention_days,rule,subtype,time_content_updated,time_created,time_updated,adaccounts}
```

I want to get "ALL" the custom audience data, what am I suppose to add in that query, so that there will be no limit? , because in the facebook graph explorer, there seems like a limit in the output and I'm not seeing the other datas that I want to see. so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before there was a "limit" parameter which you could use, but Facebook already removed is from most of the queries in a favor of paging. You should navigate through all pages to get whole list. In the and of your json response there should be a "paging" section. You go page by page until you hit the last one (you will not see "next" in paging section)

```
"paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "TmpBMk9XhNemMzTkRVMEb3hORGswTWpNMU1UTTBPakkwTnpJNE5URXpNakEyT1RFeU1BPT0ZD",
        "after": "TmpBMU56STFNelF6TlRjMEb3hGMzTURNMU56UTBPakkwTnpJNE5URXpNakEyT1RFeU1BPT0ZD"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_{ACCOUNT_ID}/customaudiences?access_token={TOKEN}&pretty=0&fields=account_id&limit=25&after=TmpBMU56STFNelF6TlRjMEb3hORGMzTURMU5TBPakkwTnpJNE5URXpNakEyT1RFeU1BPT0ZD"
    }
```

Comment: `limit` is not actually removed from most endpoints. (The maximum limit value you can use is ... well, limited, though. So using ridiculously high limits to avoid having to deal with pagination will not work in most cases.)

Comment: Yes, you right. I was a bit unclear. I was working with Facebook API for a while now and there was a time when instead of a paging there were "skip" and "limit" parameters. Which were deprecated in a favor of paging.  And i don't know is it a bug or not, but currently some Facebook's queries does not support "limit" parameter, including the query above.

Comment: `limit` is documented as part of cursor-based pagination, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging And even the `next` URL in the API output you quoted above contains `limit=25` if you look closely.

Comment: Try the request in facebok graph api explorer: act_{YOUR_ID}/?fields=customaudiences{account_id}&limit=5. This particular request will not be limited to only 5 items it will return you 25 (default value in this case).

Comment: "limit" is working fine, for example, in getting list of campaigns, when it actually limit to 5 or to 500, but not every query support it